# Objective-C ccKeyDown player movement

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, keyboard, game-physics

I currently working on a Cocos2D Mac Game in Objective-C.

I've got the movement working but i have one more question ..

I use this code to move my player, it is a fly so it needs free movement in all directions.

Keyboard event:

```
- (void)ccKeyDown:(NSEvent*)keyDownEvent
{
 // Get pressed key (code)
 NSString * character = [keyDownEvent characters];
        unichar keyCode = [character characterAtIndex: 0];

 // Player movement
 if (keyCode == 119) {
  playerMoveUp = TRUE;
 } else if (keyCode == 115) {
  playerMoveDown = TRUE;
 }
 if (keyCode == 100) {
  playerMoveLeft = TRUE;
 } else if (keyCode == 97) {
  playerMoveRight = TRUE;
 }
}

- (void)ccKeyUp:(NSEvent*)keyUpEvent
{
 // Get pressed key (code)
 NSString * character = [keyUpEvent characters];
        unichar keyCode = [character characterAtIndex: 0];

 // Player movement
 if (keyCode == 119) {
  playerMoveUp = FALSE;
 } else if (keyCode == 115) {
  playerMoveDown = FALSE;
 }
 if (keyCode == 100) {
  playerMoveLeft = FALSE;
 } else if (keyCode == 97) {
  playerMoveRight = FALSE;
 }
}
```

Gametime loop:

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
 // Get player current position
 NSInteger playerPositionX = player.position.x;
 NSInteger playerPositionY = player.position.y;

 // Player movement
 if (playerMoveUp == TRUE) {
  player.position = ccp(playerPositionX, playerPositionY + 1);
 }
 if (playerMoveDown == TRUE) {
  player.position = ccp(playerPositionX, playerPositionY - 1);
 }
 if (playerMoveLeft == TRUE) {
  player.position = ccp(playerPositionX + 1, playerPositionY);
 }
 if (playerMoveRight == TRUE) {
  player.position = ccp(playerPositionX - 1, playerPositionY);
 }
}
```

My problem is when my player is moving left it's not possible to add the up key the same time, so the player will be moving left and up. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple-simple trick: declare an array of bool like `bool arrows[4]`, where each element is an arrow button state and *true == pressed*. Now you set an array element to true in keyDown event and to false in keyUp. The last thing you need - a timer to check this array and move objects.

Actually, the timer a better solution than regular event handling because you can control "keys processing speed".